# MVC - how to reference "this.ID" in LINQ query?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller

In my controller, I have a simple method that updates a field. I want it to update a field of the *current* record. Something like:

```
public IActionResult Approve()
{
    ThisForm update = (from p in _context.ThisForm where p.ThisFormID == [**what do I put here?**] select p).SingleOrDefault();
    update.ApprovalStatus = 'Approved';
    _context.SaveChanges();       
 
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

It's going to be something super simple, but I don't know how to reference this form's ID. I have defined the method in my controller, and I have assigned the method as the asp-action in a form in my view:

```
<form asp-action="Approve">
        <input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-outline-success" />
</form>
```

Assume that the field is called "ThisFormID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `ThisFormID` as a parameter to the action `Approve()` so it will look something like this `Approve(int formId)`, I'm assuming that you have access to this `ThisFormID` when you are calling this action.

It depends on 'how' you are calling action `Approve`

Edit:

You are not passing any data when submitting form.
Your model (or rahter view model) should look like something like this:

`class FormModel { public int ThisFormID {get;set;} }`

(or you could have just this `ThisFormID` as a view model)

Your view should look like something like this:

```
@model FormModel 

<form asp-action="Approve">
  <input asp-for="ThisFormId" type="hidden" />
  <input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-outline-success" />
</form>
```

then your action could look like this:

```
public IActionResult Approve(FormModel formModel)
{
    ThisForm update = (from p in _context.ThisForm where p.ThisFormID == formModel.ThisFormID select p).SingleOrDefault();
    update.ApprovalStatus = 'Approved';
    _context.SaveChanges();       
 
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

you could look up for more examples here: [Submit form to action with parameters, Asp.Net.Core Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900617/submit-form-to-action-with-parameters-asp-net-core-mvc)

or just google how to submit form with parameters

Comment: I modified the question to show where I have defined the method in the controller and referenced the method in my view.

Comment: It was passing the model through like this: "<input asp-for="ThisFormId" type="hidden" />" that was the key. I knew it'd be super simple. Thank you!